# Honda innova 125 brake problem

Tags: honda, motorcycle, brakes

Hi I have Honda innova 125 motorcycle and I was riding and the front brake locked and I crashed the person who helped me said this was due to lack of brake fluid, now the front brake doesn’t work at all but the bike still rides, does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the brake system for air?
I guess air compression is to blame here
Brake fluid transfers the power from the handle to the brake pads with just a little fluid compression as power loss.
Air compression will take all your power just to compress and the pads will not recieve any power.
I guess through the crash the brake line caught some air and now you get the said effect of air comprtessing.

Try replacing the fluid  andde-air the system afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Riding your bike without a properly operating FRONT BRAKE is EXTREMELY DANGEROUS.
Than being said the reason your front brake is not working is probably due to air bubbles caught up in the line after your crash.
Your brakes need bleeding and a proper inspection before you can ride your motorcycle again.
If this is already done and your breaks don't work you should have your calipers checked for any seal damages and/or your brake pump for any damaged o-ring seals.
Did you happen to hit while crashing any part your braking system including calipers, levers rotor disks etc???
If that is the case have your brakes properly and thoroughly inspected.
EDIT: I stumbled myself upon a similar situation a few days ago on my dirt bike. A reason for the front brake to be engaging (but not really locking) on it's own, would be, after EXTREME braking, bubbles of air trapped in the front brake hose expand to the point they apply pressure on the calipers (and surely pushing some amount of brake oil back to the pump) without you touching the brake lever.